# PuTTY Error Connection Timed Out

Tags: windows-10, ssh, putty

I installed PuTTY on Windows 10 to connect to a workstation. On entering the IP address it remains idle for a while and says `Fatal Error, Connection Timed Out`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is (arguably) normal behavior.

Comment: change "ClientAliveInterval" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on server &or puty

Answer (score 0):

As Anaksunaman said in the comment, this is normal behavior if the target system is running Windows.

PuTTY is not used for communication with Windows systems; it is a terminal emulator mainly used for Telnet, SSH or serial RS-232.  Windows doesn't support user login via any of these methods very well.

The main use of PuTTY is in talking to linux systems via command-line interface.  Now if the target system is in fact a linux system, then the timeout suggests that the remote host does not have Telnet or SSH installed or active.  That would be an issue to take up with the administrator of the remote host.